# Boto3 - get_change(), change_resource_record_set() INSYNC takes 60 seconds to return

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, dns, boto3, amazon-route53

I'm building an API that works with AWS route53 to add, delete and update records for a specific zone.

When I'm using `change_resource_record_set()`, I'm getting a response with `status = 'PENDING'`. So my idea is to run a while loop with `get_change()` until the status will be INSYNC. in Boto3 route53 documentation they say it takes up to 60 seconds, but I think it is ridiculous to wait 60 seconds for each update. Do you have any ideas on how I can make sure the changes took place at the AWS servers?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Route 53 is a globally distributed system and each change takes time to propagate.  There is no way to verify whether a service has correctly and fully processed your change unless you ask it, using the method provided.  You could heuristically verify the change by making your own targeted DNS queries and reading the response... but that does not provide the same level of assurance.

Comment: Michael's comments are correct. On top of that remember that DNS is a globally distributed system and the fact that one part has updated does not mean that the entire globe has updated. With DNS, make the change and move on. It will "eventually" and that is the key word, at some time in the future, replicate.